# Linux Shell script to copy files from one location to another location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have a folder in my server which contains some files. These are automated that means everyday we get new files automatically which will overwrite the old ones. So want to take a back up for this data. How can i copy all these files in to a another folder by renaming the files with current date while copying.

ex : i have a folder named folder1 which contains 4 files. path for this folder is home/install/project1/folder1

```
aaa.dat
bbb.dat
ccc.dat
ddd.dat
```

now i want to copy all these four files in to a different folder named folder2. path for this folder is home/install/project1/folder2. while copying these files i want to rename each file and add the current date to the file. so my file names in folder2 should be..

```
aaa091012.dat
bbb091012.dat
ccc091012.dat
ddd091012.dat
```

I want to write a `Linux` shell script for this. Please give me some idea or some sample scripts related to this.

Comment: @JimGarrison, i tried this command...$ mv /directory_one/* /directory

Comment: @JimGarrison, for unix shell , i know the script how to copy files but for linux i dont know... if the unix commands works for linux also then its ok. i can make it out...

Comment: 98% of Unix commands have identical or very similar counterparts in Linux.

Comment: @GMRamesh: which linux flavor are you using? Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using Red Hat

Comment: @JimGarrison, thank u Jim... i will check that command now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
srcdir="home/install/project1/folder1"
dstdir="home/install/project1/folder2"
d=$(date +%m%d%y)

for srcfile in ${srcdir}/*
do
    dstfile=$(basename $srcfile)
    dstfile=${dstfile/\./${d}\.}
    cp $srcfile $dstdir/$dstfile
done
```

Comment: There are a few problems with that script; most notably, `$srcfile` will actually just be equal to `$srcdir`.

Comment: Good catch @ruakh, editing now

Comment: Just add a note that this script would not copy any files present in sub-directories of `srcdir` to ensure it is what OP expects.

Comment: Now `$dstfile` will be e.g. `home/install/project1/folder1/aaa091012.dat`, so `$dstdir/$dstfile` will be e.g. `home/install/project2/folder2/home/install/project1/folder1/aaa091012.dat`.

Comment: Nice, @ruakh - edited again

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 steps, first `cp`:

```
cp -rp source/ target/
```

Then use `rename`. But you should use Ubuntu flavor of it, which is actually Perl script. For Redhat, you might be able to install or download it from https://metacpan.org/module/rename. Unfortunately, native Redhat/Fedora rename does not support Perl regular expressions and will not work for this.

At any rate, use Perl-ish `rename` like this:

```
cd target
rename 's/\.dat$/091012.dat/' *
```

You can even use it recursively by combining it with `find` and `xargs`, something like:

```
find | xargs rename 's/\.dat$/091012.dat/'
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
    cd home/install/project1/folder1
    for f in *.dat
    do 
    cp -v $f /home/install/project1/folder2/${f%.dat}$(date +%m%d%y).dat
    done
```